# Laravel: Factories created with boolean values in column fails to pass test case with assertDatabaseHas in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit

### The Question

I have my table **sample** with columns has_value and has_condition which are boolean type created by laravel in MySQL. In Factory of the **sample** table I have set the faker value to be boolean. In test case I have passed the faker value as it is. The laravel stores the value properly but the test case with assertDatabaseHas fails as MySQL stores the values in numeric value but the faker is providing the boolean value.

### The setup

#### Migration

```php
Schema::create('sample', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedBigInteger();
   $table->boolean('has_value')->default(false);
   $table->boolean('has_condition')->default(false);
});
```

#### Model

```php
class Sample extends Model {
  
   /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'has_condition' => 'boolean',
        'has_value' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

#### The factory

```php
$factory->define(Sample::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'has_condition' => $faker->boolean,
        'has_value' => $faker->boolean
    ];
});
```

#### The test case

```php
use DatabaseMigrations;

public function test_is_being_stored()
{
  $data = factory(Sample::class)->make()->toArray();
  $user = factory(User::class)->create()
  $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('some.route.store'), $data)
    ->assertSessionHasNoErrors()
    ->assertStatus(200);

  $this->assertDatabaseHas('sample', $data)
}
```

The result is as follows

```php
Failed asserting that a row in the table [campaign_tax_years] matches the attributes {
    "has_condition": true,
    "has_value": true
}.

Found: [
    {
        "id": 27,
        "created_at": "2020-07-01 07:36:52",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-01 07:36:52",
        "has_condition": 1,
        "has_value": 1
    }
]
```

The value check in the database are not typecasted checks. But the value being stored is correct. I am unable to understand why Laravel is not casting the values and then checking for column types.

#### Various Item Versions

Laravel: 6.8.x
Mysql: 5.7.29
Phpunit: ^8.0

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method in `TestCase` class like this:

```
protected function convertBooleansToInteger($attributes)
{
    return array_map(fn($v) => $v === false ? 0 : ($v === true ? 1 : $v), $attributes);
}
```

Then us:

```
public function test_is_being_stored()
{
  $data = factory(Sample::class)->make()->toArray();
  $user = factory(User::class)->create()
  $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('some.route.store'), $data)
    ->assertSessionHasNoErrors()
    ->assertStatus(200);

  $data = $this->convertBooleansToInteger($data)

  $this->assertDatabaseHas('sample', $data)
}
```

Comment: Which version of laravel did the method "convertBooleansToInteger" is introduced?

Comment: As I mentioned, you should add this method to the `TestCase` class!